# How to change the Viewport background color?

Tags: interface, customization, theme

I'm trying to change the Viewport background color.
But I can't seem to find the right settings.

[image]

Anyone knows where to find it?

Comment: Yes I meant the viewport.

Answer (score 12):

> Edit :). This answer by @Moonboots is actually way more useful:
> → [How do you change the background color of the 3D viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/184728/78972)

---

It's a bit buried in submenus, but don't worry.

**Preferences** *> Themes > 3D View*
[image]

Scroll down to: *Theme Space > Gradient Colors >* **Gradient High/Off**
[image]

Comment: Guys, seriously, stop upvoting this, and see [moonboots' answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/184728/78972) :)

Answer (score 3):

The background for the 3D vieport can be set in the user preferences > Themes > 3D view > Theme Space > Gradient Colors > Gradient High/Off

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do it, Themes keeps the colors consistent with any new projects you create, for example setting a blue theme would make every background in every new blender file blue.

And then there is *Viewport Shading*, (alot quicker) where you can change the background for the individual .blend file when in *Studio/MatCap/Flat shading mode*.

[image: Where to find viewport color]

Keep in mind this color will not show when you render the image, it only appears in your view port, to change the background in an animation/ render you would have to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

`Cmd/Ctrl ,` > Themes > Preferences > 3D Viewport > Theme Space > Gradient Colors > Gradient High/Off