# How do you change the background color of the 3D viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

I see tutorials where people have the background color of the 3D viewport blue and green. Where do you change this?

Thanks,
Rusty

Answer (score 9):

To change the default background color, it's in the *Preferences* as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164502/how-to-change-the-viewport-background-color).

To change the file's background color you need to display the *Viewport Shading* panel, choose *Background > Viewport* instead of *Theme*, and change the color below.

[image]

Comment: Oh, this is a good way I had no idea about :).

Comment: well, it completes your answer, it depends if he wants to change the default background color or just the file background color

Comment: It's definitely more intuitive :)