# Color changes drastically after eevee render

Tags: rendering, camera, eevee-render-engine, color, color-management

this might be a beginner question but i can't seem to understand why my colour ends up differently after rendering the image on eevee. Here is the viewport display of my setup:

[image]

image 1: **Red** background

From this view, I hit f12 to render the image from camera using eevee:

[image]
image 2: **Blue** background

As we can see, the **viewport shows a Red** background while the **render shows a Blue** background. I'm still quite new to blender and this might be due to a rookie mistake, but it's confusing the hell out of me and i'll appreciate the help :)

Comment: Here's a reference to viewport background: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164502/how-to-change-the-viewport-background-color ... not seeing a background in eevee but there is probably a setting (Scene Properties: Background Scene?). The viewport seems like it is rendered with Eevee, but you are seeing one difference.

Comment: In the second image you posted, there seems to be evidence of Z-fighting in the top left. Is there a chance you made a blue "display background" in the same place as the red one, but hid it in the viewport? Hidden objects will still be visible in renders. It looks like it's trying to display 2 backgrounds at the same time. Z-fighting is another way of saying "blender doesn't know which one's supposed to be in front".

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Yes thank you, this did the trick. I made multiple scenes and duplicated the background, which i turned off in viewport display but not in render which corresponded to the phenomenon you brought up.